# Can not set both minDate and maxDate in eonasdan datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have an `eventStartDate` and `eventEndDate`.

When the start date is selected, I want to set min and max dates for the end date.

Below code works, with one quirk:

when you select the end date, it does not accept the date first time, instead it defaults to today's date.  When you select it a second time, it works.

```
  $('#start_date_picker').on('dp.change', function () {

    let eventStartDate = moment($('#start_date').val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY');
    let minEventEndDate = eventStartDate.clone().add(1, 'days');
    let maxEventEndDate = eventStartDate.clone().add(30, 'days');

    $('#end_date_picker').data("DateTimePicker").clear();
    $('#end_date_picker').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(maxEventEndDate);
    $('#end_date_picker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(minEventEndDate);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's no `#start_date` element in the HTML.

If you want to set `end_date_picker`'s `minDate` and `maxDate` after selected a date in `#start_date_picker`, you can use the variable that [`dp.change()`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange) passed.

> ```
> e = {
>     date, //date the picker changed to. Type: moment object (clone)
>     oldDate //previous date. Type: moment object (clone) or false in the event of a null 
> }
> ```

```js
$(function () {
  $('#start_date_picker').datetimepicker();
  $('#end_date_picker').datetimepicker();
});

$('#start_date_picker').on('dp.change', function (e) {

    let eventStartDate = moment(e.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
    let minEventEndDate = eventStartDate.clone().add(1, 'days').startOf('day');
    let maxEventEndDate = eventStartDate.clone().add(30, 'days').endOf('day');

    $('#end_date_picker').data("DateTimePicker").clear();
    $('#end_date_picker').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(maxEventEndDate);
    $('#end_date_picker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(minEventEndDate);
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='input-group date' id='start_date_picker'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>

<div class='input-group date' id='end_date_picker'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, very helpful.  Problem still persists, but I now realize that its ONLY when I try to select the last allowable date.  For example, in your code snippet above, select a start date of 1 May, then try to select end date of 31 May.  It won't accept it.  Try a different end date, then retry 31 May, and it works...

Comment: @KimPrince You can set the time to the end of the day and it would be clickable.